# Find Cheapest Possible Path Recursively

Tags: c++, recursion, path-finding

I am attempting to write a solution to find the cheapest possible path through an array with integer values stored as game locations.  THe idea is to go from the first index to the last index and incur the cheapest cost depending upon which index you decide to "stop" on.  You can either move to the next index from where you are or you can jump over that index to the next index (ind + 1 vs ind +2) until you arrive at the end.

What I have below is returning a massively negative integer, which obviously is very wrong.  I am fairly certain it has to do with how I am controlling current location and i'm unsure how to do it recursively.  It's easy to do iteratively, but recursively is proving difficult.  **It must be done recursively**  Any thoughts to get me down the right path?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

using namespace std;

const int GAMEBOARD_SIZE = 6;

int DetermineCheapestPath(int gameBoard[], int lowInd, int highInd, int currentLocation);

int main()
{
    int gameBoard[GAMEBOARD_SIZE] = { 0,3,80,6,57,10 };

    cout << "The cheapest possible path for this board is " << DetermineCheapestPath(gameBoard, 0, GAMEBOARD_SIZE - 1, 0) << endl;

    return 0;
}

int DetermineCheapestPath(int gameBoard[], int lowInd, int highInd, int currentLocation)
{
    int lastValue;
    int currentValue;
    //base case 
    if (lowInd == highInd)
    {
        currentLocation -= 1;
        return gameBoard[highInd];
    }
    else
    {
        lastValue = DetermineCheapestPath(gameBoard, lowInd + 1, highInd, currentLocation + 1);

        if (gameBoard[currentLocation] > gameBoard[currentLocation - 1] && currentLocation != 0 && lowInd != 0)
        {
            currentValue = gameBoard[currentLocation - 1];
            currentLocation -= 2;
            return lastValue + currentValue;
        }
        else if (gameBoard[currentLocation] < gameBoard[currentLocation - 1] && currentLocation != 0 && lowInd != 0)
        {
            currentValue = gameBoard[currentLocation];

            currentLocation -= 1;
            return lastValue + currentValue;
        }
        else
        {
            return lastValue + gameBoard[currentLocation];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: On the 1st call `currentLocation` is passed in as `0` so `gameBoard[currentLocation - 1]` is undefined behaviour

Comment: Right and that's probably because current location isn't being updated actively throughout the entire iteration.  When I try and pass currentLocation by reference i get a whole bunch of errors thrown at me

Comment: _"When I try and pass currentLocation by reference..."_  this `currentLocation + 1` is not a valid reference parameter.

Comment: @RichardCritten That helped I understand and got it working.  Thanks for the help!